# Can't Access Network Drives through VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, dhcp, network-share, windows

My issue is that when I'm outside the office I can't access any of my network drives. I can't UNC to them, through the FQDN or IP address.  For example,  domain.local\folder, or  172.26.6.2\d$. Nothing works remotely.  I can also ping everything just fine, names and IP addresses alike. The firewall does not show anything being blocked, and I am an administrator with the proper access to do this. Not only does this affect me, but it affects everyone under our network umbrella.  I did some dcdiags at home and I got the following.
I ran dcdiag /s:domain.local

```
Directory Server Diagnosis
Performing initial setup:   [domain.local] Directory Binding Error 1727:   The remote procedure call failed and did not execute.
This may limit some of the tests that can be performed.   * Identified AD Forest.
Done gathering initial info.
Doing initial required tests
Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\domain02      Starting test: Connectivity         [domain02] DsBindWithSpnEx() failed with error 1727,         The remote procedure call failed and did not execute..
Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your         firewall settings.         ......................... domain02 failed test ConnectivityDoing primary tests   ds
Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\domain02      Skipping all tests, because server domain02 is not responding to      directory service requests.

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom      Starting test: CrossRefValidation         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test         CrossRefValidation
Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom      Starting test: CrossRefValidation         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test         CrossRefValidation
Running partition tests on : Schema      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom      Starting test: CrossRefValidation         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
Running partition tests on : Configuration      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom      Starting test: CrossRefValidation         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
Running partition tests on : domain      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom         ......................... domain passed test CheckSDRefDom      Starting test: CrossRefValidation         .........................  domain passed test CrossRefValidation
Running enterprise tests on : domain.local      Starting test: LocatorCheck         Warning: DcGetDcName(GC_SERVER_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1722         A Global Catalog Server could not be located - All GC's are down.         Warning: DcGetDcName(PDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1722         A Primary Domain Controller could not be located.         The server holding the PDC role is down.         Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1722         A Time Server could not be located.         The server holding the PDC role is down.         Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error         1722         A Good Time Server could not be located.         Warning: DcGetDcName(KDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1722         A KDC could not be located - All the KDCs are down.         ......................... domain.local failed test LocatorCheck      Starting test: Intersite         ......................... domain.local passed test Intersite
```

A little lost.  It used to work, not sure when it stopped...

**UPDATE....**

When I capture the information from the server to the vpn location. This is what I get.

[Wireshark Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF8OA.jpg)

Comment: Could be a routing problem.  Make sure you security appliance has a static route from your domain's subnet that points to your VPN's subnet.

Comment: To clarify: Over VPN, you are able to ping the remote server which you are attempting to access, but are not able to access the file shares? Is this a site-to-site VPN, or is this a dialed VPN from a Windows client?

Comment: Currently, if you can login to our VPN client on your machine, then you will be added to VPN VLAN.  We have rules in place so that anything inside that VPN can access their User Vlan. Which is the same vlan as if they were at work.

Correct, over VPN, I am able to ping the remote server. The VPN is site to site.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about your VPN server it's difficult to make good statements about the cause. I suspect that you've got something filtering the traffic between your VPN clients and the server computers.

I'd start by installing "Network Monitor" (or Wireshark, or your favorite sniffer) on one of the server computers and capturing traffic while a client attempts to access the server computer via File and Print Sharing. You should see traffic on TCP port 445 and / or port 139 (depending on client and server versions) coming from the VPN client to the server. If you don't, then something is filtering that traffic.

If you do see the traffic then the details you uncover in the trace should give you a next place to look (access denied errors, etc).

Comment: UPDATE....

When I capture the information from the server to the vpn location. This is what I get.

Wireshark Snippet